# How to get the last number from the loop

Tags: java, for-loop, primes

I'm working on application which should show the biggest factor of a number and it has to be the prime number too.

That's my app:

```
public class BiggestFactor {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double dev = 0d;
    for (double j = 0; j < 984654354654d; j++) {

        if (984654354654d % j == 0) {
            dev = j;
        }

        // show dev when is a prime number
        double i;
        for (i = 2; i < dev; i++) {

            double n;
            n = dev % i;

            if (n == 0) {
                // do nothing - not a prime number
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i == dev) {
            System.out.println(dev);
        }
    }
}
}
```

and my question is how to get as a result just the last number? In my case I get bunch of numbers.

Comment: How about starting loop from end and printing the first number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *minimal* change is to declare a new variable `result`:

```
    double result = -1;
```

and instead of printing `dev`, simply save its value in `result`:

```
        if (i == dev) {
            result = dev;
        }
```

Then, at the end of the function, print `result`:

```
    System.out.println(result):
```

Comment: by the way is that the most efficient way to calculate that?

Comment: @knowbody: No, it's definitely, definitely not. You should store `984654354654d` in a variable -- say, `x` -- and whenever you find a factor, you should divide `x` by that factor and retry the same factor. In addition to letting you terminate faster (by lowering `x`), this will also let you eliminate the test for `j`'s primality, because it's implicit in the algorithm. Furthermore, you can terminate as soon as `j * j > x`, since at that point the only remaining prime factor is `x` itself (which is what you actually want to print).

Comment: @knowbody: Also, this didn't occur to me before, but -- in Java, a `double` and a `long` are the same size (64 bits), so `long` actually supports a larger contiguous range of integers. So you should use `long` rather than `double`. (From an efficiency standpoint that's only a linear improvement, but it's also better from a clarity-and-maintainability standpoint.)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class BiggestFactor 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double dev = 0d;
        double last = dev;
        for (double j = 0; j < 984654354654d; j++) 
        {
            if (984654354654d % j == 0) 
            {
                dev = j;
            }
            double i;
            for (i = 2; i < dev; i++) 
            {
                double n;
                n = dev % i;
                if (n == 0) 
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (i == dev) 
            {
                last = dev;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(last);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done a little refactoring and moved the logic of checking prime in another function for better understanding. Also change the number to `1001` to increase the verification speed :P

```
public class BiggestPrimeFactor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double dev = 0d;

        double numberToCheck = 1001d;

        for (double j = 0; j <= numberToCheck / 2; j++) {

            if (numberToCheck % j == 0 && isPrime(j)) {

                dev = j;

            }
        }

        System.out.println(dev);
    }

    private static boolean isPrime(double n) {
        boolean prime = true;

        for (long i = 2; i <= n / 2; i += 2) {

            if (n % i == 0) {

                prime = false;
                break;

            }
        }

        return prime;
    }
}
```

Basically, what is does it to continuously update `dev` to be the current biggest prime factor.

Comment: will this work for `numberToCheck = 1006d;`? What will it print?

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for catching that mistake. Updated the code now.

Comment: good; now make it run for the original huge number in less than 0.1 sec, by changing the algorithm as explained in comments to ruakh's answer. :)

Comment: @WillNess ruask's answer does not have any optimization. With that it will loop as many times as mine (if not more). With this way he will have a nested loop just as mine (which in my cas, is refactored into a function)

Comment: "in - comments - to". :)